# Why is this DataFrame not doing what I'm trying to do?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to learn Pandas for DA and I have managed to figure out merge and merge 2 DF together, but I'm trying to sum a new column whilst column x != column y

```
merged_by_country["total_shows"] = merged_by_country["show_id"] + merged_by_country["count"] #(lambda x, y: x != y)
test = merged_by_country.copy()

def set_shows(df):
    for r in df.iloc:
        if r[1] == r[3]:
            r[-1] = r[1]
        else:
            r[-1] = r[1] + r[3]
    return df
set_shows(test)
```

But I'm getting 'SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame' which I want it to do, but whenever I call the DF again, nothing changes... even tried copying the df in the func then performing the loop and passing back the new copied df but nothing happens.

```
             country  show_id        first_country  count  total_shows
              Jordan        1               Jordan      1            2
         Philippines        1          Philippines      1            2
United Arab Emirates        1 United Arab Emirates      1            2
         Switzerland        1          Switzerland      1            2
             Senegal        1              Senegal      1            2
```

edited with the sample of merged_by_country dataframe.

Comment: Should mention using jupyter notebooks with VS Code and this is the entire cell-- not sure if that was implied or not.

Comment: I don't understand the question.

Comment: Please update your post with a sample of `merged_by_country` dataframe. `print(merged_by_country.head().to_string(index=False))`

Comment: Appologies, added the sample.

Comment: The `SettingWithCopyWarning` is raised on the first line?

Comment: Doesn't give me a line number, shows after the code cell is ran.

Comment: Try to isolate `merged_by_country["total_shows"] = merged_by_country["show_id"] + merged_by_country["count"] #(lambda x, y: x != y)` in one cell. Does it raised the warning?

Comment: No it doesn't im assuming that its caused in the function when im trying to set the value of 'total_shows' equal to either 'show_id' or 'show_id + count'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `np.where`:

```
# Renamed 'merged_by_country' to 'df' for readability
df['total_shows'] = np.where(df['show_id'] == df['count'],
                             df['show_id'],
                             df['show_id'] + df['count'])
```

Comment: Works perfectly thank you.  New to python and programming so never knew where existed within np.. haven't really used it :)

Comment: An interesting function too is `np.select` a switch case function.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['total_shows'] = df.show_id
idx = df[df.country!=df.first_country].index
df.loc[idx, 'total_shows'] = df.loc[idx, 'show_id']+ df.loc[idx, 'count']
```